# How to automate excel to google search mulitple search queries each opened in different IE Tabs

Tags: excel, vba, search, web-scraping

I want a VBA macro to make a column of cells automatically opened in multiple tabs in Internet Explorer.
The Cells are the search query for google, each opened in multiple tabs with the defined range.

```
Sub GoogleSearch()

    Dim objIEBrowser

    Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIEBrowser.Visible = True

    Dim SearchTerm As String

    For Each Cell In Range("D6:D14")

        SearchTerm = Cell
        SearchTerm = Replace(SearchTerm, " ", "+")

        objIEBrowser.navigate "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & SearchTerm

    Next

End Sub
```

This results in the macro opening the last cell (D14) all other cells are not searched nor opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are navigating to each url within the same window. You need to open new tabs or windows. Constants to flag what to do [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd565688(v=vs.85)).

It's a small number of cells so I haven't read those search values into an array. Normally, I would read those into an array, and loop that array, rather than incur the repeated I/O cost of going back and forth, from the sheet, in the loop over each cell.

### **New windows:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GoogleSearch()
    Dim objIEBrowser, searchTerm As String, i As Long, cell As Range
    Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIEBrowser.Visible = True

    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D14") 'better to use explicit sheet name
        searchTerm = Replace$(cell.Value, " ", "+")

        If i = 0 Then
            objIEBrowser.navigate "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & searchTerm
        Else
            objIEBrowser.document.parentWindow.execScript "window.open('" & "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & searchTerm & "');"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Stop
     objIEBrowser.Quit
End Sub
```

**Or:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GoogleSearch()
    Dim objIEBrowser, searchTerm As String, i As Long, cell As Range
    Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIEBrowser.Visible = True
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D14") 'better to use explicit sheet name
        searchTerm = Replace$(cell.Value, " ", "+")
        objIEBrowser.Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & searchTerm, CLng(1)
    Next
    Stop
     objIEBrowser.Quit
End Sub
```

---

### **New tabs:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GoogleSearch()
    Dim objIEBrowser, searchTerm As String, i As Long, cell As Range, flag As Long
    Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIEBrowser.Visible = True
    i = 0
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("D6:D14") 'better to use explicit sheet name
        searchTerm = Replace$(cell.Value, " ", "+")
        flag = IIf(i = 0, 1, 2048)
        objIEBrowser.Navigate2 "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & searchTerm, CLng(flag)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Stop
     objIEBrowser.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: This does it! thank you very much, has been boggling me for the last 4 hours. I am trying to wrap my head around what you wrote on the CLng statement, using the "i" variable.
I created a working macro before, unfortunately the work environment deleted the file when switching to a different PC. It looked a lot like your input from the "or" part, if I remember it correctly I used the activesheet statement which I did not this time.
Amazed by the quick response and in depth knowledge.

Comment: Still interpeting the things you wrote.

Comment: The flag for new window is 1 and for new tab is 2048. I evaluate whether I am visiting the first url i =0 or any after and set the flag as Clng(1) for new window first url, otherwise CLng(2048) for new tab. I had to look up the constants.