# Is there a way to automate running multiple external search queries from within Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Within Google Sheets (or Excel), I would like to run a repetitive search query.

I have not found a formula that will allow me to achieve my goals.

I have a column A of company URLs. I'd like Column B to (automated) retrieve a list of search results that have the CEO of that company's name.

I was told there was a way to do this with Python but have no Py-fu to use. If there's a way to get this info via XLOOKUP function, I'm not seeing how since the data is not likely on the URL site of the company. Google could easily generate the list of CEO names but I need to automate it since the CSV file I have is a fairly long list.

I tried to find a Python script that could help and I've had no such luck. I'd prefer to have a formula within Google Sheets. Maybe Google Apps Scripts could help?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide your current script and the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Apologies. I don't have a script that I've found that works at all. What I'm trying to do is create a script that will resolve the need.

Comment: Need to be a script using google sheets?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a Google Sheet. It can be any spreadsheet capable of handling a long column of company URLs.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site. It needs more focus and that you show what you have tried among other things. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

Please check this thread - [How to automate excel to google search mulitple search queries each opened in different IE Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971445/how-to-automate-excel-to-google-search-mulitple-search-queries-each-opened-in-di)

Here is used Microsoft VBA, so then you would use excel instead of google sheets. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Not all questions should be answered. See [answer].